# Hide Woocommerce Checkout Tickbox

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I am creating a site which requires customers to store their card details for payments at a later date. They pay a deposit up-front and then the organisation charges the saved card details at a later date. By default the stipe gateway offers a solution to save card details to their stripe account (which can then be used to recharge later). Instead of offering this option, I want to enforece it. From a legality point of view you must overtly make the customer agree to storing of card details but this will be next to the complete checkout button in the text stating "you agree to t's and c's and are happy to store the payment details entered for use to charge the remainder on the day of your appointment etc.

I was trying to use the following footer function

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
<script>


    /* Making new payment save checkbox checked by default */
    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').prop("checked", true);


</script>
<?php } );

        
        ?>
```

which works great, however when I try and add a hidden, disabled or readonly element to the checkbox that doesn't work, for example I tried each of the following

```
    add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
<script>


    /* Making new payment save checkbox checked by default */
    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').prop("checked", true);

    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').attr("hidden", hidden);
    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').attr("type", "hidden");
    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').hide();

    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').prop("hidden", hidden);
    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').prop("type", hidden);
    jQuery('#wc-stripe-new-payment-method').prop("type", "hidden");


</script>
<?php } );

        
        ?>
```

How can I tick this tickbox but make it a hidden element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Applied CSS fix instead setting `display:none!important` on the ID of that element via CSS